# How to join two aggregate views, when one is a derrived view?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm pretty inexperienced with SQL in general, so I'm struggling with this. I know this looks messy and inefficient (so open to suggestions on improving that too!)

I have two queries that are pulling and aggregating data from three different tables. The first query is pulling from a single table, the second is aggregating data from 2 different tables.

```
SELECT
    ifnull( `rt_poes`.`Account`, 'Total Compliant Spend' ) AS `Account`,
    round( sum( IF ((( `rt_poes`.`Platform` = 'Google' ) AND ( `rt_poes`.`Ad_Type` = 'Search' )), `rt_poes`.`Cost`, 0 )), 2 ) AS `Compliant Google Search`,
    round( sum( IF ((( `rt_poes`.`Platform` = 'Microsoft' ) AND ( `rt_poes`.`Ad_Type` = 'Search' )), `rt_poes`.`Cost`, 0 )), 2 ) AS `Compliant Bing Search`,
    round( sum( IF ((( `rt_poes`.`Platform` = 'Google' ) AND ( `rt_poes`.`Ad_Type` = 'Shopping' )), `rt_poes`.`Cost`, 0 )), 2 ) AS `Compliant Google Shopping`,
    round( sum( IF ((( `rt_poes`.`Platform` = 'Microsoft' ) AND ( `rt_poes`.`Ad_Type` = 'Shopping' )), `rt_poes`.`Cost`, 0 )), 2 ) AS `Compliant Bing Shopping`,
    
    round( sum( IF ((( `rt_poes`.`Platform` = 'Google' ) AND ( `rt_poes`.`Ad_Type` = 'Search' )), `rt_poes`.`Cost`, 0 )), 2 ) + 
    round( sum( IF ((( `rt_poes`.`Platform` = 'Microsoft' ) AND ( `rt_poes`.`Ad_Type` = 'Search' )), `rt_poes`.`Cost`, 0 )), 2 ) 
    AS `Compliant Country Spend`
    
FROM
    `rt_poes` 
WHERE
    ((
            `rt_poes`.`field1` LIKE '% condition1%' 
            ) 
        OR ( `rt_poes`.`field2` LIKE '% condition2%' ) 

GROUP BY
    `rt_poes`.`Account` WITH ROLLUP 
ORDER BY
    sum( `rt_poes`.`Cost` )
```

This works well and generates a nice overview of the data I'm looking for as below.

The second query is:

```
SELECT ifnull( Account, 'Total All Platform Spend' ) AS Account, Round(SUM(Cost), 2) AS total_platform_costs 
FROM 
(SELECT Account, Cost FROM QTD_Account_Report
UNION ALL
SELECT AccountName, Spend FROM Bing_QTD_Account_Report) AS DerivedTable
GROUP BY DerivedTable.Account WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY total_platform_costs
```

This generates another nice view of the data from another table that I'm looking for too.
The output of both is correct.

[image: This is the output of both]

Now, I'm trying to join both on the account column. Essentially just add the second column from the second output on to the output of the first query.

The problem I'm having is that whenever I try to use a standard join, I get an error that MySQL does not support this syntax.

Is there another way to join the two or modify the second so that I can have a single view with both like below? Or do I have to create a whole new table for this?

[image: Wanted Output]

Comment: The queries can easily be joined on the column account. Post your query that joins them.

Comment: I don't have a query that joins them, I don't know how to do it. I only know how to join on two tables. So after adding the WHERE clause in the first table, adding: JOIN ON , then entering a select query with a subquery in it, gives me the syntax error. MySQL workbench doesn't give an error, and Navicat doesn't provide support for such a join (popup saying so).

I'm not asking anyone to do this for me, just to point me in the right direction on how to join a select statement with another select statement that contains a subquery. I think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven’t done MySQL in a while, but simply joining the second query should work. Is this what you did?

```
select
    ifnull(rt_poes.Account, 'Total Compliant Spend') as Account,
    round( sum( if(rt_poes.Platform = 'Google'    AND rt_poes.Ad_Type = 'Search',   rt_poes.Cost, 0)), 2) as `Compliant Google Search`,
    round( sum( if(rt_poes.Platform = 'Microsoft' AND rt_poes.Ad_Type = 'Search',   rt_poes.Cost, 0)), 2) as `Compliant Bing Search`,
    round( sum( if(rt_poes.Platform = 'Google'    AND rt_poes.Ad_Type = 'Shopping', rt_poes.Cost, 0)), 2) as `Compliant Google Shopping`,
    round( sum( if(rt_poes.Platform = 'Microsoft' AND rt_poes.Ad_Type = 'Shopping', rt_poes.Cost, 0)), 2) as `Compliant Bing Shopping`,

    round( sum( if(rt_poes.Platform = 'Google'    AND rt_poes.Ad_Type = 'Search',   rt_poes.Cost, 0)), 2) + 
    round( sum( if(rt_poes.Platform = 'Microsoft' AND rt_poes.Ad_Type = 'Search',   rt_poes.Cost, 0)), 2) as `Compliant Country Spend`
    
    round(SUM(DerivedTable.Cost), 2) as total_platform_costs 
from rt_poes
    left join (select Account, Cost
               from QTD_Account_Report
               UNION ALL
               select AccountName, Spend
               from Bing_QTD_Account_Report) as DerivedTable on DerivedTable.Account = rt_poes.Account
where rt_poes.field1 like '%condition1%' or rt_poes.field2 like '%condition2%'
group by rt_poes.Account WITH ROLLUP 
order by sum(rt_poes.Cost)
```

It would be helpful if you quoted the specific error message you got, as well as the query that caused it.

Comment: I was doing the join after the where, and leaving the final total_performance_costs select in the subquery. Thank you for that. I modified my query and it worked. Appreciate you taking the time. Now I know how to do it in future.